# Tags feeling a little shy again

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, design, meta

When editing a question the tags are feeling a little shy and aren't displaying themselves fully.

[image: tag b0rked]

The inline tag editing does not have the same problem but the tags jump around a little as well. I'm fairly sure that this has happened before but it was fixed and I can't find the bug report.

This only appears to be happening on MSE.

I'm on Chrome 34.0.1847.116 on Windows 7 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Do you have a non-standard zoom setting, by any chance? I don't see this in Chrome on OS X.

Comment: Nope, it's at 100% @Martijn.

Comment: Then it prolly is a Windows vs Mac font issue. Yay Mac!

Comment: I occasionally see the same on Chrome on Win 8.1. It usually only happens after I've removed a tag.

Comment: Having written this post however, it's just got considerably better. They're getting a little braver now. But, they do a little jump still.

Comment: I tried to edit your post on Chrome Canary and can reproduce the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome 36.0.1918.0 on Windows 7.

Comment: Reproduced in Safari 7.0.3 on OS X 10.9.2

Comment: Reproduced in Chrome `34.0.1847.116 m` and Internet Explorer `11.0.9600.17041`

Comment: `[status-nonrepro]` here, on Chrome 32.0.1700.102 Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: Reproduced on Aurora 31.0a2 (2014-06-09), Win7 x64

Comment: No-repro on Firefox 29.0.1, Win7 x64 :p

Comment: Reproduced on Firefox 30.0, Win7 x64 :D

Comment: I can't reproduce using latest IE, Opera, FF or Chrome (Windows 8.1)

Comment: @Oded maybe Windows 7 then? I am also able to reproduce.

Comment: @ShadowWizard - I also tried Chrome on Windows 7. Do you have any additional information? I will try to reproduce again, but so far, no luck.

Comment: @Oded also note that when editing, inline edit is fine (10k or mods) the bug is only in the edit page itself, e.g. http://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/229833/edit

Comment: @Oded http://i.stack.imgur.com/xsAtY.png

Comment: Ah. The edit page. I was looking at inline tag/question edits only.

Comment: @Oded yep, wonder how OP discovered it, being 10k user. :)

Comment: I think it's been fixed in the latest Chrome version but was present earlier. Everyone's complaining about ones that are now old @Shadow (or I might have right-clicked on edit and opened in a new tab for some reason or another)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Took a bit to hunt down. Actually looking at the right place helped.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Hmm... feature request: when adding a status tag to a question, automatically add this tag to all questions closed as duplicate of that question. Feasible? It would surely save lots of dev time! :-)