# The left border is eating the questions!

Tags: bug, edits, design, meta

Possibly (probably) related to [Tags feeling a little shy again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229833/tags-feeling-a-little-shy-again), cancelling an edit on a question seems to move the question left, outside the border, which means that I can't see the left hand side.

> [image: chomp!]

To reproduce, click edit then click cancel.

I can only solve by a hard refresh and this is only happening on MSE

I'm on Chrome 34.0.1847.116 on Windows 7 if it makes a difference.

Comment: Nope, not on Chrome on OS X, again. Time to switch! :-P

Comment: No repro on Chrome on Win 8.1..

Comment: I'm tempted @Martijn, I really am...

Comment: No-repro on Chrome on Windows 7...

Comment: Do you get inline post editing at 2k @Qantas? I can't remember and it could be due to that.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards: at 2k you get inline post editing, but not inline tag editing.

Comment: [Oh my goodness, the tag `min-width`s...](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QqYWI.png) Argh...

Comment: I'm confus-ed @michael :-(.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards I'm not a fan of this whole `min-width`-on-the-tags thing, and it was particularly ...irritating(?) to see a row of four of them, all excessively padded on the sides.

Comment: No repro Chrome Zorin <2K rep.....and and >2K rep